# How to call component Leaflet few times in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, leaflet

when i call one time my component, my leaflet map is ok :-)

```
<map-affiche [lat]="lat" [lng]="lng"></map-affiche>
```

but when i call few times, i have an error :
ERROR Error: "Map container is already initialized."

html :

```
<div id="map" class="center"></div>
```

typescript :

```
  @Input() lat: number;
  @Input() lng: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    const map = L.map('map', {
      center: [this.lat, this.lng],
      zoom: 19,
      attributionControl: false
    });
   }
```

Have you an idea ??? thanks !!!

Comment: could it be cause you are referring to the same id="map" ? I think you need different ids so it can differentiate them

Comment: Thanks @ihorbond !!! i think you have a good idea but i don't know how make it !!! html ok : <div id="{{ 'map' + id }}" class="center"></div> typescript ko :     let variable = 'map' + this.id;

    var map = L.map(this[variable], {
      center: [this.lat, this.lng],
      zoom: 19,
      attributionControl: false
    });

Comment: posted an answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

component.ts

```
// I assume you have a unique id if not you could use some random value or maybe combination of lat + lan...
public mapId: string = "map" + this.id; 
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
    const map = L.map(this.mapId, {
      center: [this.lat, this.lng],
      zoom: 19,
      attributionControl: false
    });
   }
```

component.html

```
 <div id="{{mapId}}" class="center"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @ihorbond !!! it is ok for you ??? i have an error : ERROR Error: "Map container not found."

Comment: I havent ran it. What if you initialize map in ngAfterViewInit instead ? if you want to post a reproducible example to stackblitz I'll take a look

Comment: It is OK @ihorbond !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thanks youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu                    very very much !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!        https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jtreqk    only thing and it is ok : if i don't move mouse, the map don't display full !!! i search :-)

Comment: glad could help :) regarding map not displaying full I suggest you post a new question